# Button on touchbar is randomly activated without being pressed

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

Recently, I encountered some weird interaction with my MacBook Pro 13 with touchbar. Initially, I used Pock to customize my touchbar with macOS dock. My button on the touchbar randomly activated such as adjust brightness, volume although I didn't touch them. I stopped using Pock because I thought it was the trouble. However, the problem is still there. My Siri is automatically activated and my screen is locked while I'm using it again.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this? Or at least how can I describe this problem to Apple properly because I cannot reproduce it intentionally.

Comment: Have you deleted Pock or just stopped using it ? If you haven’t deleted it you should try to.

Comment: I only stopped using it. I will try to uninstall it.